# Linux Bash how to use xargs on a program that requires input from stdin/files?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to call `./prog` with arguments from `args.txt`, but meanwhile, `./prog` also reads from file input `in.txt`

I tried `cat args.txt | xargs ./prog < in.txt` but it doesn't work.

I understand if the program doesn't need input, `cat args.txt | xargs ./prog` should work.
But in this case, how should I write it..?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `./prog $(cat args.txt)` won't work if args.txt have special characters. for example, I might want to pass contents: "arg1 arg2" arg3 as 2 arguments, where the 1st argument is "arg1 arg2" as a whole, the 2nd is arg3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU xargs has a `-a` option to pass in arguments from a file.

```
xargs -a args.txt ./prog < in.txt
```

If your xargs doesn't have `-a`, you could try one of these alternatives:

```
./prog $(< args.txt) < in.txt

cat args.txt | xargs bash -c './prog "$@" < in.txt' --
```

The second one is ugly but also more robust when given arguments with whitespace, particularly if you use `xargs -0`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and clean answer. `./prog $(< args.txt) < in.txt` works for me. Could you explain the difference between this and `./prog $(cat args.txt) < in.txt`? Does '<' also read file contents to stdout, so that the contents are caught by $()? Isn't '<' an input redirection?

Comment: `$(<file)` is a shorter way of writing `$(cat file)`. Basically no difference. Use `cat` if you find that more readable.

Comment: I see. Then I might consider the 2nd solution since `cat file` won't work if the contents have special characters like whitespaces